# Java Web Start - IllegalStateException: zip file closed

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, illegalstateexception

I'm facing a strange exception in my Java Web Start application.

It verifies at application start during the loading, then the application crashes with this exception: IllegalStateException: zip file closed.

It doesn't happen in all computer Clients, but I think it doesn't depend on the Java version because I've tried lots of different versions in different O.S..
Also, it doesn't happen at every program execution, only occasionally.

Do you have any ideas of what can cause this?

I used Java Mission Control tool and investigated. 
I found some NoSuchMethodError when the application starts. Maybe those Errors could be the problem ?

Comment: Which zip file is closed? It might be related to the timeout of the server method (thinking about a web server).

Comment: How can I know which file has been closed?

Comment: Please print more details of the stacktrace. That might have that information.

Comment: Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: Both application and console crash. I redirected the println output to a file, and I see the exception. But maybe I'd have to get a log\trace of a lower level (Java Virtual Machine crash? )

Comment: I'm searching for a detailed log that can help with this issue: I know the hs_err logs generated when the JVM fails or the log \ trace generated by the Java Console and saved in the AppData folder ... Is there something else that I should try or that's all?